# Jest/Enzyme | Cannot destructure property on null or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my function for `ComponentDidMount`. But I get this error:`Cannot destructure property params on null or undefined`.

The function I want to test is this one:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }
```

And it is depended on this one:

```
  fetchUser = () => {
    getUser(this.getUserUsername()).then(username => {
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      });
    });
  };
```

which in return is depended on this one:

```
  getUserUsername = () => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const { params } = match;
    console.log(params, 'params'); // return an object { username: "john" }
    console.log(match, 'match');
    **// return an object
    // { isExact: true
    //  params:
    // username: "john" .
    // __proto__: Object
    // path: "/management/users/:username"
    // url: "/management/users/john" }**
    return params.username;
  };
```

And here is my test:

```
  describe('componentDidMount', () => {
    it('should call fetchUsers function', () => {
      const match = { params: 'testName' };
      const params = match;
      const fetchUserFn = jest.fn(params);
      const wrapper = shallow(<UserDetailsScreen fetchUsers={fetchUserFn} />, {
        disableLifecycleMethods: true
      });
      wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
      expect(fetchUserFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
```

But I get the above error. Not sure what I need to do, and while I found answers similar to this problem, the answers don't solve my problem.

CODE for getUser:

```
export const getUser = username => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.GET_USER(username)
    // The GET_USER is an endpoint for 
    // that specific username
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```

The above returns a promise.

Comment: please add code for getUser function

Comment: parmas? That looks like a spelling mistake rather than a code error.

Comment: No the `parmas` is my spelling error. Syntax is correct.

Comment: Just updated the desc, and added the code for `getUser`. @akshay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below syntax

```
describe('componentDidMount', () => {
  it('should call fetchUsers function', () => {
    const match={params: {username: 'akshay'}, isExact: true, path: "", url: ""}
    const fetchUserFn = jest.fn(match);
    const wrapper = shallow(<UserDetailsScreen match={match} fetchUsers={fetchUserFn} />, {
      disableLifecycleMethods: true
    });
    expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<h2>Details for 1</h2>)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

also you can use [containsMatchingElement](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/containsMatchingElement.md)

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring `parmas` for some reason, did you mean `params`?

Try to search throughout the APP for `parmas` and check if you have a spelling mistake.